# Not getting data from retailers website using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm try to scrape the price of particular website. The one i've been practicing to scrape is https://www.harveynorman.com.au/asus-f402wa-ga019t-14-inch-laptop.html

```
import json
import requests

session = requests.Session()
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
jar.set('incap_ses_572_39856', 'wuEvYO64IwcG0nzjJijwB+oi3FwAAAAA0mUuBJjlb55z2q8aD0K/Ug==; SLIBeacon=5cdc22e9ece4f; SLIUserID=168578381; __utma=137779881.1422157795.1557930730.1557930730.1557930730.1; __utmc=137779881; __utmz=137779881.1557930730.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; _gcl_au=1.1.866045692.1557930730; _ga=GA1.3.1422157795.1557930730; _gid=GA1.3.1396003810.1557930731; _caid=067e96e9-dfea-4ff0-bd40-7729d204dc3c; _cavisit=16abbe8672e|; gdprContinent=NOT-EU; SLIBeacon=5cdc22e9ece4f; _fbp=fb.2.1557930734066.1140960424; _hjIncludedInSample=1; inptime0_3986_au=0; com.silverpop.iMAWebCookie=5621042d-8a53-3d48-d144-beb9db181190; com.silverpop.iMA.session=83ab8550-a067-6e50-7239-411cde0ad75d; com.silverpop.iMA.page_visit=-303946284:; reloadLists=true; inpsession_3986_au=03BA299D-6307-61F5-DD5E-F3F561CCA385; __gads=ID=d4a1dce2efb966ac:T=1557930751:S=ALNI_MaarXiiUHzcInDtMvu3BU8YWN9ziw; LPVID=FhMTIwOTc4YzY5N2VjNDhl; LPSID-58902652=tfROAwmpTgu9u-avZulSqg; inptime_3986_au=120; __utmb=137779881.2.10.1557930730; _gat_UA-5631569-15=1; _gat_UA-5631569-18=1')

session.cookies = jar
r = session.get('https://www.harveynorman.com.au/applybuy/apply/product?id=283011&price=297&_=1557930879834')

print(r.text)
```

My expected result was to find a json data to use or the whole html. Unfortunately, even using cookies I haven't get some sort of data. The result was:

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script>
<body>
</body></html>
```

Need help how with this kind of issue without using selenium or scrapy. Thanks!

Comment: Please, clarify what url you are interested in. Thanks.

Comment: The url above is what i'm interested, the harveynorman.com.au

Comment: Incapsula is one of those anti-ddos services that protects sites like this from bots like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is secured with Anti-bots (CDN). Incapsula is a one of the major Anti-bot network in the market. It uses advanced ML based algorithms to detect whether it's a bot or human based on so many parameters including Browser Fingerprinting.

There are few ways we can try site like this,

1. Using Proper Headers which impersonate the browser
2. Using Premium proxies (ie. residential proxies) such as Microleaves,Crawlera
3. Proper time intervals for each request and proxy rotations

There are even some pre-defined libraries are developed to bypass the firewall like incapsula-cracker-py3.

Whatever you are trying, the code should impersonate the actual human.